# php backend api - allow access only from website

Tags: javascript, php, api, security, rpc

I am having an interesting problem here. I have a standard front website, "example.com". That domain is routed through CloudFlare to my origin. Front-end of that website calls my PHP backend API by requesting the file /api.php from Javascript.

My question here is: how to allow requests from that website's javascript only ?

I want to prevent direct access to the /api.php file from -for example -  shell (curl). I want to allow requests only from my website's frontend.

Comment: Not possible. If it needs to be accessible outside, it will be accessible in any way people might think to access it.

Comment: get the ip address of the website and allow only this ip in you site

Comment: @SamiKuhmonen - thats i afraided of after my research...

Comment: @RafaelShkembi - remember that  website is behind of CloudFlare so I'm receiving CloudFlare's IP address on my backend side.

Comment: Doable with OAuth, but might be an overkill.

Comment: Ok, so another, more general question - how to recognize requests on my api is request comes from my website (from javascript) or comes from direct request of api file from - for example - shell's curl ?

Comment: Requests *from javascript* do not come from your website, but from user's browser, unless your *javascript* is an node app.

Comment: So general there is no solution for that ? @AlexBlex - I understand it, but still thinking about some solution in general or theretically way.

Comment: You could try this: set a certain Cookie  (with a random key, or something) when the user gets on the main front-end, and then check if it exists in `api.php`. This would kind of protect it a bit, but it will still remain vulnerable as this can be reproduced in curl after some time of work.

Comment: @artur99 - I tried that as a hotfix for a while, but it stops a lot of normal requests (looks like bots without support for cookies) :)

Comment: @webcitron The general solution is OAuth. Your backend issue a token to your frontend to sign requests. Requests with correct signature are likely to be from "your website"

Comment: Aah :D but the bots should be allowed, while curl shouldn't? I don't think this would be possible, as long as curl can be easily set to behave like a bot and get the page.

Comment: @artur99 - exactly, its a theoretical problem instead of strict programatic. and this make it hard to solve

Comment: @AlexBlex - sounds ok (to make token for every normal user navigating trough website, add that token to request and check it on api side). it makes few programming problems here (for example how to implement it without big impact of api performance), but I think its a solution :)

Comment: I don't  see any *progrmming* problems here.  The technology is quite mature.  The only problem is cost,  hence it might be an overkill.